# beautifulsoup scraping nytimes

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape articles from the NY Times and keep getting a very long list of errors. I was wondering if someone could help point me in the right direction. Below is the URL of the article in question, my code, and the output from the console. Any help would really be tremendous.

article: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/10/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-flight.html?ref=world&_r=0

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Ask user to enter URL
url = "http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/10/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-flight.html?ref=world&_r=0"

# Open txt document for output
txt = open('ctp_output.txt', 'w')

# Parse HTML of article, aka making soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

# Write the article title to the file    
title = soup.find("h1")
txt.write('\n' + "Title: " + title.string + '\n' + '\n')

# Write the article date to the file    
try:
    date = soup.find("span", {'class':'dateline'}).text
    txt.write("Date: " + str(date) + '\n' + '\n')
except:
    print "Could not find the date!"

# Write the article author to the file    
try:
    byline=soup.find("p", {'class':'byline-author'}).text
    txt.write("Author: " + str(byline) + '\n' + '\n')
except:
    print "Could not find the author!"

# Write the article location to the file    
regex = '<span class="location">(.+?)</span>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
byline = re.findall(pattern,str(soup))
txt.write("Location: " + str(byline) + '\n' + '\n')

# retrieve all of the paragraph tags
with open('ctp_output.txt', 'w'):
    for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
        txt.write(tag.text.encode('utf-8') + '\n' + '\n')

# Close txt file with new content added
txt.close()

Sample output from console: 
andrews-mbp-3:CTP Andrew$ python idle_test.py
Please enter a valid URL: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/10/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-        flight.html?ref=world&_r=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "idle_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the NYT has an [API](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from list of errors (also called the `traceback`), the (*first*) error happens on line 20, in the part when you are making a call to `urllib`. So, check out what you're passing into that function. Your variable `url`, which `urllib` expects to be a string, has no quotes around it, which makes me wonder how the code didn't throw an error earlier.

I said *first* error, earlier, because your code when you first write it (this is true for most programmers and always true for new programmers) will have many errors in it. Learning to program is in many ways learning how to interpret the errors (the `traceback`) from the computer.

#### Update

You just changed the definition of `url` to a `raw_input` function. Please don't do this, because it makes it harder to read and debug the code. `urllib` is having an issue with the variable `url`. Obscuring the value of the variable `url` makes it harder to debug. From experience, I'd suggest that maybe including (or not) `http` or some such syntax could be messing you up there -- but I can only guess at that if I can't see `url`.

Comment: Thank you for this as I am a new programmer. But the in real code I am using, the url is pulled in when I ask the user for input. I edited it up above.

Comment: see my update, above.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: sure. I'm just saying set the variable like this `url = "http://google.com"` instead of this `url=raw_input("type in a url")`. That way I can see what url it is breaking on, so I can try to reproduce your error.

Comment: Just implemented the change

Comment: Ok, so I just ran this code. When I ran it I got a different error. When I put the url into a web-browser to actually see what is there, my web browser auto-redirected to `"http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/10/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-flight.html?ref=world&_r=1"` (identical except the last character). This new url then worked for me.

Comment: It seems to only work when that last bit of the URL is added &_r=1". Although the output is a prompt to have me log in to the NY Times. What output were you getting?